# Terraform output as a variable in pipeline yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

Im trying to create variables for the output shown below so i can use it in a azure devops pipeline yaml. I have managed to insert the code for the outputs but i dont know how to get the actual output from terraform to use those inputs in the rest of the steps

Any help would be appreciated!

Error:

```
 Warning: No outputs found
│ 
│ The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined outputs
│ are empty. Please define an output in your configuration with the `output`
│ keyword and run `terraform refresh` for it to become available. If you are
│ using interpolation, please verify the interpolated value is not empty. You
│ can use the `terraform console` command to assist.
```

OUTPUT

```
output "appid_tfazsp" {
  value     = data.azuread_application.tfazsp.application_id
  sensitive = true
}

output "pass_tfazsp" {
  value     = azuread_application_password.tfazsp.value
  sensitive = true
}

output "stg_SASPass" {
  value     = data.azurerm_storage_account.stg.primary_access_key
  sensitive = true
}
```

BuildDefinition

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

  paths:
    include:
      - /TF/variables.tf
      - /TF/main.tf

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

variables:
  - group: hawaVB
  
steps:
  - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
    displayName: 'Install Terraform'
  - script: terraform version
    displayName: Terraform Version
  - script: terraform init
    displayName: "Terraform Init"
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=storage_account_SASPass;isOutput=true]$(terraform output -raw outputvar)"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pass_tfazsp;isOutput=true]$(terraform output -raw outputvar)"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appid_tfazsp;isOutput=true]$(terraform output -raw outputvar)"
              workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TF
  - script: az login --service-principal -u $(appid_tfazsp) -p $(pass_tfazsp) --tenant $(tenant_id)
    displayName: 'Log Into Azure'
  - script: terraform init -backend-config=resource_group_name=$(rg_name) -backend-config="storage_account_name=$(storageAccount_name)" -backend-config="container_name=$(cont_name)" -backend-config="access_key=$(storage_account_SASPass)" -backend-config="key=$(state_file)"
    displayName: "Terraform Init"
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TF
  - script: terraform plan -var=$(appid_tfazsp) -var="$(pass_tfazsp)" -var="tenant_id=$(tenant_id)" -var="subscription_id=$(subscription_id)" -var=$(VMAdminPass) -out="out.plan"
    displayName: Terraform Plan
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TF
  - script: terraform apply out.plan
    displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TF
```

Tried various ways of setting up the code to use it as a variable but no go

Answer (score 0):

To view an output, you need to **first run the plan**.

Make sure to pass the same path you're passing on `plan`.

Also, the `output` command takes in the variable you're trying to get. (e.g. *appid_tfazsp*)

You're trying to get "outputvar" which isn't defined.

In the end, your pipeline should look like this:

```yaml
# Omitting the rest above the Bash task...
  - script: az login --service-principal -u $(appid_tfazsp) -p $(pass_tfazsp) --tenant $(tenant_id)
    displayName: 'Log Into Azure'

  - script: terraform init -backend-config=resource_group_name=$(rg_name) -backend-config="storage_account_name=$(storageAccount_name)" -backend-config="container_name=$(cont_name)" -backend-config="access_key=$(storage_account_SASPass)" -backend-config="key=$(state_file)"
    displayName: "Terraform Init"
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TF

  - script: terraform plan -var=$(appid_tfazsp) -var="$(pass_tfazsp)" -var="tenant_id=$(tenant_id)" -var="subscription_id=$(subscription_id)" -var=$(VMAdminPass) -out="out.plan"
    displayName: Terraform Plan
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TF

  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=storage_account_SASPass;isOutput=true]$(terraform output -state="out.plan" -raw stg_SASPass)"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pass_tfazsp;isOutput=true]$(terraform output -state="out.plan" -raw pass_tfazsp)"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appid_tfazsp;isOutput=true]$(terraform output -state="out.plan" -raw appid_tfazsp)"
              workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TF
  - script: terraform apply out.plan
    displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TF
```